# Parent's data change does not update child component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following:

```
Vue.component('times-updated', {
    template: '<span>Times Updated: {{ timesUpdated }}</span>',
    data: function() {
        return {
            timesUpdated: this.$parent.myData.timesUpdated
        }
    }
});


var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    data: function() {
        return {
            myData: {}
        }
    }
})

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: `${window.location.href}/json`, // This just returns an array : array.timesUpdated: 2 etc
    }).done(function (data) {
        vm.myData = data; // changes this data
    });
}, 1000)
```

and am using the following html:

```
<div class="test">  
    <times-updated></times-updated>
</div>
```

I poll a REST API that returns an array which includes a timesUpdated property:

```
{
    timesUpdated: 5
}
```

My intention is that every second I use jQuery's `$.ajax` method to call the API, update the `myData` data object on `vm`, which would then update the `times-updated` component.

The code works on initial page load, the `times-updated` component can retrieve the value on its parent's `myData` property, but whilst I have confirms that `vm.myData` does reflect the new value from the API, the component doesn't update its display to show the new count.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not plug in vue-resource with vue? https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: Also, the problem might be the fact that 'data' on Vue instance is a callback instead of an object. That callback is required only in components.

Comment: I'll look into vue-resource, that looks cool!

Comment: You were correct about the data function, i changed it to an object and it worked great, thanks!

Comment: If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: your welcome.  I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data function is only called once during the life cycle of the component; when it is initially created. So essentially your component is just displaying the value as it existed when the component was created.

Additionally, it's generally bad practice to reach out of a component to get a data value. Vue is [props down, events up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components). You should convert your component to use a property.

```
Vue.component('times-updated', {
  props:["times"],
  template: '<span>Times Updated: {{ times }}</span>',
})
```

The fact that you are using a function to define the Vue in this particular case doesn't really matter, it's just not a typical practice. Components *require* a function because they need an isolated scope.

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wdQBVe?editors=1010).

Answer (score 1):

*That callback is required only in components*

```
    // vue instance
    new Vue({
        data: {
            status: true
        }
    };

    // vue components (callback)
    Vue.component('custom-component', {
        data: function() {
            return {
                status: false
            }
        }
    });
```